# DBX `named_parameters` are not working correctly

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, argparse, dbx

I have cluster in Databricks and i want ot run my local code on this cluster using [DBX](https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). But i have some issues with `named_parameters` **How can I use the correct format of dictionary(`{"t": "hello"}`) in `named_parameters` to run my code in cluster and get this parameters value?**

My code:

[image]

Run with this `named_parameters`:
[image]

Run with correct `named_parameters`:
[image]

Comment: Please, do not use images, provide the text directly.

Answer (score 0):

use below in deployment.yaml

```
named_parameters:
  t: 'hello'
```